# Запрос для подсчета среднего времени сессии

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `time_user` с полями:

```
user_id
event
time
```

В неё пишутся события, которые генерирует пользователь.

Как можно вычислить среднюю длину сессии по всем сессиям всех пользователей, если под сессией подразумевается последовательность событий одного пользователя, промежуток между которыми(событиями) не превышает 5-ти минут?

Я набросал запросец, но он считает неверно.

```
SELECT COUNT(t.user_id) cnt_session, t.user_id 
FROM time_user t 
WHERE ROUND(
    (
        (
            SELECT t1.`time` 
            FROM time_user t1 
            WHERE t1.user_id = t.user_id AND t1.`time` > t.`time` LIMIT 1
        )
         - t.`time`
    ) / 60
) > 5 
GROUP BY t.user_id 
ORDER BY t.`time` ASC
```

Запрос создания таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `time_user` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `event` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
  INDEX `time` (`time`)
  )
  COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
  ENGINE=InnoDB
  ;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Я хотел сказать используйте рекурсивные запросы, но потом заметил в вашем запросе обратные апострофы и понял, что это MySQL и их у вас нет. Всегда указывайте какой именно диалект SQL используете, от этого зависит с какой стороны вообще подходить к запросу. И самое главное - `time` у вас какой тип данных, что в нем лежит ?

Comment: @Mike , да, верно, mysql используется. Дополнил вопрос кодом `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Поправил ответ что бы работал с таймстампами

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое. Работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(length)
  from (
        select user_id, snum, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,min(time),max(time)) length
          from(
               select user_id,time,
                      @snum:=if(@user=user_id and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,@ptime,time) <= 60*5,
                                @snum,@snum+1) snum,
                      @user:=user_id, @ptime:=time
                 from time_user,
                      (select @ptime:=0, @user:=0, @snum:=0) A
                order by user_id, time
              ) B
         group by snum
      ) C
```

Подзапрос `B` нумерует сессии подряд, ориентируясь на id пользователя и время события из предыдущей записи (при сортировке по пользователю и времени), запомненное в переменных. Подзапрос `C` группирует по полученным номерам сессий и вычисляет длину сессии как разность между минимальным и максимальным временем в ней. Внешний запрос берет среднюю длину сессии (в секундах). Если надо сессии в разрезе пользователей добавьте соответствующий `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.user_id, count(t.user_id)+1 as cnt_session, (SELECT count(DISTINCT t2.user_id) FROM time_user t2) as cnt_users 
from time_user t 
WHERE ROUND(((SELECT t1.`time` FROM time_user t1 WHERE t1.user_id = t.user_id AND t1.`time` > t.`time` ORDER BY t1.time ASC LIMIT 1) - t.`time`) / 60) > 5 
GROUP BY t.user_id 
ORDER BY t.`time` ASC
```

Осталось только как-то посчитать суммарное время сессии.. и поделить его на cnt_session и cnt_users