# Сложный SQL запрос к двум таблицам

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. Не могу решить следующую задачу:

Есть несвязанные таблицы connections_history и  users_devices. Таблица **connections_history** хранит информацию о подключениях (***дата, время, IP-адрес, URL с которого пришел пользователь, URL посещенной страницы***).Таблица **users_devices** хранит информацию об устройствах пользователей (***IP-адрес, имя браузера, имя ОС***).

Необходимо одним запросом вывести следующую информацию

1. IP-адрес
2. Браузер
3. ОС
4. URL, с которого пользователь впервые посетил сайт
5. URL, на который пользователь зашел последний раз
6. Кол-во уникальных URL, которые посетил пользователь
7. Общее время пребывания на сайте

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Вбили в голову, что есть какие-то и несвязанные таблицы и с ними ничего сделать нельзя? Так вот - это не так. Можно связать любые таблицы. Отсутствие foreign key не является препятствием для установления связи. `select * from connections_history c join users_devices d on c.ip = d.ip` - вот вам связь по ip. Дальше сами как-нибудь

Comment: Есть ли в этих двух таблицах время события?

Comment: Проблема не в объединении таблиц, а в поиске и выводе нужных столбцов из разных строк согласно условиям одним запросом. Дата и время в таблице connections_history указывают на дату и время подключения пользователя.

Comment: @mirypoko Какой у вас все таки диалект SQL. Вот то определение времени с 30 сек. интервалами оно на sql в принципе реализуемо, но ооочень сильно зависит от конкретной СУБД. И я надеюсь дата-время это один столбец типа datetime иначе там жуткие навороты получатся ...

Comment: @Mike Я использую MySQL. Дата и время это разные столбцы, я решил считать общим временем пребывания на сайте время с первого подключения. Я сделал запрос, который получает всю необходимую информацию, но он состоит из нескольких небольших запросов, а нужно одним. Мои навыки и знания мизерны, сделать из этого набора запросов что-то вменяемое у меня не выходит.

Comment: @Mike Получившийся запрос:  SELECT users_devices.ip, users_devices.browser, users_devices.os, (SELECT refer_url FROM connections_history WHERE users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip ORDER BY date, time LIMIT 1) AS firstReferURL, (SELECT target_url FROM connections_history WHERE users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip ORDER BY date, time DESC LIMIT 1) AS lastTargetURL, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT target_url) FROM connections_history WHERE users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip ORDER BY date, time DESC LIMIT 1) AS countUniqueTargetURL, (SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),date) FROM

Comment: @Mike продолжение запроса: connections_history WHERE users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip ORDER BY date,time LIMIT 1) AS daysOnSite FROM users_devices .

Comment: @mirypoko Разные столбцы это зря. переход суток очень сложно будет учитывать. предположим мы сделаем учет разрыва не более 30 секунд ... но учесть что 23:59:59 и 00:00:03 в соседних дней - это из одного интервала ... надо в одну колонку datetime собирать дату/вермя

Comment: @mirypoko не так уж все и плохо в вашем запросе. при получении уникальных url order by и limit не нужны. По поводу проверки интервалов времени между записями в mysql подходят только переменные. вот тут я что то подобное вычислял: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527928/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/527975#527975 НО там одно поле дата-время, с двумя полями сложно слишком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос, который я смог создать своими силами:

```
 SELECT
      users_devices.ip,
      users_devices.browser,
      users_devices.os,
      (SELECT
        refer_url
      FROM
        connections_history
      WHERE
        users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip
      ORDER BY
        date, time
      LIMIT 1) AS firstReferURL,
      (SELECT
        target_url
      FROM
        connections_history
      WHERE
        users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip
      ORDER BY
        date DESC, time DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS lastTargetURL,
      (SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT target_url)
      FROM
        connections_history
      WHERE
        users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip) AS countUniqueTargetURL,
      (SELECT
        DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),date)
      FROM
        connections_history
      WHERE
        users_devices.ip = connections_history.ip
      ORDER BY
        date, time
      LIMIT 1) AS daysOnSite
    FROM
      users_devices
```

Answer (score 2):

Таблицы можно соединить по IP адресу.
Под общим временем пребывания на сайте имеется ввиду что?

- конкретное время(сумма интервалов пребывания на сайте)? У вас логируется только факт подключения - а значит рассчитать невозможно
- время от факта первого подключения
- количество дней, в течении которых пользователь хотя бы раз заходил на сайт

Случаи 2) и 3) реализуются по-разному в разных СУБД. Укажите какую вы используете.

Статистика, собранная таким образом, будет о адресах, а не о пользователях. Надо быть готовым к коллизиям, которые возникнут из-за пользователей которые заходят с разных ip, и пользователей, которые не имеют "белых" ip, т.е. к вам могут постучаться разные машины с одного ip.
Чтобы собрать информацию именно о пользователях - нужно "заставлять" их проходить аутентификацию и отображать это в своих таблицах.

Comment: Общее время пребывания я рассчитываю так: заполняю массив массивами, хранящими подключения, интервал между которыми менее 3 минут. Затем нахожу разницу между последним и первым подключением этого массива + 30 секунд. У каждого пользователя только 1 ip, браузер и ОС, это не проект, а просто задача.